# React Native StyleSheet.create pass props?

Tags: react-native, coding-style, stylesheet

is it possible to pass props top the StyleSheets?
If not what is the best alternative to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I have a variable as a style I prefer to use as state and therefore 
use it in the style

like :

```
<p style={{height:this.state.height}}>complicated </p>
```

you can use both

```
<p style={styles.paragraph,{height:this.state.height}}></p>
```

Comment: hmm so I can just use inline styles? :/

Comment: yeah I think so

Comment: I got a JSX error from the use both option, I fixed it by adding both styles in an array like so:
<p style={[styles.paragraph,{height:this.state.height}]}></p>